# Border image below H2

Tags: css

I want to add a image below each H2 in my stylesheet. I tried background image but it covers the wording. I also tried border-image but it fails to work (not sure if I understand it correctly.

Is it possible and how can I achieve it with just CSS

```
 // Sample CSS
 #content_area h2 {
     color: #107408;
     -moz-border-image:url(h2_background.png) 30 30 round; /* Firefox */
     -webkit-border-image:url(h2_background.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari */
     -o-border-image:url(h2_background.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera */
     border-image:url(h2_background.png) 30 30 round;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go back to your original h2 and do something like this:

```
h2{
     background:#ffffff url('myimage.png') no-repeat left bottom;
     padding-bottom:4px;
}
```

The padding will add extra space in which the image can sit

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `:after` pseudoelement.

> The ":after" pseudo-element can be used to insert some content after
>   the content of an element.
>
> The following example inserts an image after each  element:
>
> **Example**:
>
> ```
> h2:after {
>    content:url(smiley.gif);
> }
> ```

Citation from [CSS Pseudo-elements](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp).

Comment: Thank you for the answer Michal, although it works in adding the picture, I am unable to position it to not overlap the actual wording of the h2, nor can I resize it so that it remains in the correct diameters. I am assuming :after is limited to properties?